# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in wp theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I was updating my client's website and I encountered this error.

I looked in the file where the error was and it's this code:

```
function asset_path($filename) {
  $dist_path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/';
  $directory = dirname($filename) . '/';
  $file = basename($filename);
  static $manifest;

  if (empty($manifest)) {
    $manifest_path = get_template_directory() . '/dist/' . 'assets.json';
    $manifest = new JsonManifest($manifest_path);
  }

  if (array_key_exists($file, $manifest->get())) {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $manifest->get()[$file];
  } else {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $file;
  }
}
```

especially, this code in question

```
  if (array_key_exists($file, $manifest->get())) {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $manifest->get()[$file];
  } else {
    return $dist_path . $directory . $file;
  }
```

What's wrong with this code above and how do I fix it?

Comment: What does `manifest->get()` look like? Is it [this](https://github.com/roots/sage-lib/blob/b9adfbd72faf997b226d5a9f06b8ea74260e72fd/Assets/JsonManifest.php#L31)?

Comment: Sounds like `$manifest->get()` is returning null rather than an array. Either verify the value before using it in `array_key_exists` or do something like `array_key_exists($file, $manifest->get() ?: [])` to replace that value with an empty array